# Invoke javaScript function on click event of ASP.NET button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I would like to do multi things with one button click. Is this possible if I'm using ASP.NET web page and javaScript.

I have one button, and onClick event I need to do somethings in backed, but I need as well to invoke one javaScript function on the front end.

Is this possible using C#? And if it is how can it be done.

P.S. I've found some solutions on internet, but all of them are obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ASP Buttons have the [`OnClientClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx) property which can be used to fire client-side JavaScript in addition to operations on the server side.

It's also possible to block server-side operations with based on the result of the client-side JavaScript - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414904/asp-net-webforms-and-validation/34415084#34415084) for more on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes use an ASP Button control. Set the OnClick event to your server side function and the OnClientClick to your client side function.

Note if you want to execute both the client and server click events you need to either return true in the OnClick event to execute the PostBack, or remove the OnClick event all together and register the client side function as a start up script on the server side event.